# Razor - how to cast from this.Page (dynamic WebPageBase.Page) to System.Web.UI.Page

Tags: asp.net-mvc, dotnetopenauth, razor

I'm trying to use DotNetOpenAuth with Razor/MVC3. Most of DotNetOpenAuth HTML helpers are accepting System.Web.UI.Page as one of parameters, which works fine standard using WebForms engine but does not with Razor. Is it possible to cast dynamic WebPageBase.Page into System.Web.UI.Page somehow?

Thanks, Antonin

Comment: Which Html helper class in DotNetOpenAuth are you referring to that takes `System.Web.UI.Page`?  I might be able to find you an alternative way to get the same thing done.

Comment: Andrew, I'm talking specifically about MVC OpenId helpers like OpenIdSelectorScripts. What is strange is that I see new version of these helpers under https://github.com/AArnott/dotnetopenid/blob/v3.4/src/DotNetOpenAuth/Mvc/OpenIdHelper.cs that do not require Page reference but when I take latest compiled version of DotNetOpenAuth.dll (talking about 3.5.0.10259), it still has old version of these helpers (I see you changed that file on Sept. 16). Any reason why change did not make it yet to compiled version? Many thanks, Antonin

Comment: v3.5 isn't released yet (it's only a CTP).  Each official release collects all fixes to previous version releases.  But hearing feedback like this helps prioritize when we release versions or merge branches to resolve this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are totally different objects. So, no, you cannot cast or convert into a System.Web.UI.Page.

But [this article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/136062/OpenID-With-Forms-Authentication) might help you further.

Comment: broken link: 404: page not found

Answer (score 3):

System.Web.UI.Page is part of the Web Forms page model and is totally unrelated to Razor.  A Razor page inherits from System.Web.WebPages.WebPage which isn't part of the same hierarchy.  As GvS mentioned, the "Page" property is a different object in Razor.  In Razor, that property is just a C# dynamic object that provides a shortcut for accessing PageData values.  For example: `PageData["foo"]` is the same as `Page.foo`.

Comment: Thanks a lot, guys. Both answers are correct, I just cannot mark both, so picking first one :-) For the time being, I simply used the fact that you can combine Razor and WebForms view engines and simply encapsulated those helpers that need Page reference into WebForms partial view that I'm calling from Razor view. This way it works fine.